# Simple PHP / MySQL data results

Tags: php, mysql

I grabbed this piece of code off the Internet and modified it slightly to fit my needs but it doesn't work and I don't know why. I'm sure I've overlooked something but I don't know enough about PHP to know what I'm doing wrong. The `uid` is showing up, but nothing else. I'm just trying to get information from the MySQL data based on the user's session id. I checked the database to make sure that the `uid` that shows matches the data -- it does.

```
<?php

include("connect.php");
session_start();

$uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' . $uid . '");

if ($result) {
   echo "Connect"; } else
   { die('Invalid query: '.mysql_error()); }

$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<br>ID: ", $uid;
echo "<br>Full Name: " .$info['full_name'] ;
echo "<br>User Name: " .$info['user_name'] ;
echo "<br>";

?>
```

p.s. - Yes, I know that `mysql_query` (and other syntax like it) has been deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $uid . "'"); // not ' . $uid . '
```

**NOTE:** You were searching for `. ID .` not actual ID

Answer (score 2):

Query should be as

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $uid ");
```

Assuming id is int in the table

You had

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' . $uid . '");
                                                        ^....   ^.... was the issue.
```

Comment: Yeah I know but getting little older so cant forget the old school way of writing query i.e. quotes for string date etc and no quotes for integer :)